# PHP display different adcode if its a erotic genre

Tags: php

I am trying to create a small code for my moviesite for not displaying adsense code if the movie is in a erotic genre (id 2916). I got this so far but it gives the adcode foreach genre that the movie is in, i hope someone can help,

```
<?php
    foreach ($this->movie['genres'] as $key => $genres):
      if($genres['id'] == "2916"):
      echo "adult ad code";
      else:
      echo  "adsense code";
    endif;
    endforeach;
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$adult = false;
foreach ($this->movie['genres'] as $genre) {
    if ($genre['id'] == "2916") {
        $adult = true;
        break;
    }
}
if ($adult) {
    echo "adult ad code";
} else {
    echo "adsense code";
}
```

Comment: thanks for your quick response but i get 'Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '}' in ../Movie/Index.phtml'

Comment: Left out a `{`. Fixed.

Comment: i get a new error; syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE in

Comment: Another typo, fixed. Are you totally incapable of doing your own debugging?

Comment: Work great now Thanks! and yes i am pretty incapable of doing debugging i am just try to find out this by trial and error

Answer (score 0):

Blatantly ripping off Barmar's code, here are some alternatives so you can handle flagging multiple genre's as 'adult':

```
$adult = false;
foreach ($this->movie['genres'] as $genre) {
    switch($genre['id']) {
        case "2916":
        case "2917":
        case "2918":
            $adult = true;
            break 2;
    }
}
if ($adult) {
    echo "adult ad code";
}
else {
    echo "adsense code";
}
```

or:

```
$naughty_ids = array('2916','2917','2918');
$adult = false;
foreach ($this->movie['genres'] as $genre) {
    if( in_array($genre['id'], $naughty_ids) ) {
        $adult = true;
        break;
    }
}
if ($adult) {
    echo "adult ad code";
}
else {
    echo "adsense code";
}
```

Comment: Your second and third versions don't work because you're not accessing the `id` element of the sub-arrays.

Comment: @Barmar fixed the second and removed the third since that's not really viable anymore. Thanks.